# Failed to use React Router v6 - Navigation from <Login /> to <Home /> with <Navigation /> does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to create a simple application focused on React `router`.
I would like that after clicking on the Login button(there will be a `form` for authentication in the component), the user will be redirected to the Menu page(Navigation component).
In this case, it looks like I click the button, but only the `URL` changes.
I tried to add `Routes` and `Route` component to Login component...)

```
<div>
    <Link to="/home" >
        Login
    </Link>
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
    </Routes>
</div>
```

but in this case the Menu works in such a way that when I click on the `Link` e.g. about, the About component is not displayed.
So I don't know if there is a bug somewhere between the `Navigation` and Login components or if I'm going about it completely wrong.

index.js

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";

const baseUrl = document.getElementsByTagName("base")[0].getAttribute("href");
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <BrowserRouter basename={baseUrl}>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import Login from "./components/Login";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Login />
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Login.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
const Login = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Link to="/home" style={{ padding: 5 }}>
        Login
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

[I have pasted code already to codebox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-routing-3jrp7s?file=/src/components/Router/MyOutlet.jsx)

Comment: Clicking the "Login" link seems to correctly navigate to `"/home"` in the linked sandbox. What isn't setup in the sandbox though are any routes to navigate to. What exactly is the issue or problem you need addressed? Please [edit] to clarify the issue and to include a complete and relevant [mcve] *in the post*.

Comment: @DrewReese Hi Drew. My goal is to have Login component as default `"/"` route. After clicking the button (later if the user is authenticated) redirect to the "/home" where is main content and menu.

Comment: Is there something preventing you from declaring the routes and rending `Login` on the root `"/"` route?

Comment: @DrewReese Sorry sir, I do not understand what you mean. I am missing routes somewhere? Where?

Comment: Yes. In your sandbox `index.js` renders a `BrowserRouter` and `App`, `App` renders `Login`, `Login` renders a `Link`. No routes. However, there is a `MyOutlet` component that is rendering some routes, but this component is unused. Do you need to juggle these components around a bit and add the appropriate route for the `Login` component?

Comment: I thought `MyOutlet` is used when `Navigation` is rendered inside `Home` on the adress `"/home"`

Comment: It would be, if `Navigation` was also used. Like I asked, do you need to juggle these components a bit to be rendered, and to add a route for the login page? I can provide an answer with what I *think* you are trying to achieve if that's helpful.

Comment: @DrewReese I would appreciate any kind of help, so yes you could try it. But I am little bit confused, why the components(mentioned in my previous comment) are not used?

Comment: They are unused because they are not imported and used anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the sandbox only the `Login` component is rendered by the `App` component.

If you want `Login` to be rendered on the root `"/"` route, alone without the nav menu, then these are the changes I suggest:

1. Refactor `MyOutlet` to render the `Navigation` component and `Routes` and various routes. Add a route on `"/"` for the `Login` component. Create a new layout route component to render the `Navigation` component with an `Outlet` for nested routes and wrap all but the `"/"` route.

   ```
   import React from "react";
   import { Routes, Route, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
   import Navigation from "../Navigation";
   import Home from "../Home";
   import About from "../About";
   import Login from "../Login";
   import NoMatch from "../ErrorView/NoMatch";

   const NavLayout = () => (
     <>
       <Navigation />
       <Outlet />
     </>
   );

   const MyOutlet = () => {
     return (
       <Routes>
         <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
         <Route element={<NavLayout />}>
           <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
           <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
           <Route path="*" element={<NoMatch />} />
         </Route>
       </Routes>
     );
   };

   export default MyOutlet;
   ```
2. Remove `Navigation` from the `Home` component

   ```
   import React from "react";

   const Home = () => {
     return (
       <div>
         <div>Toto je home komponenta</div>
       </div>
     );
   };

   export default Home;
   ```
3. Update `App` to render the updated `MyOutlet` component.

   ```
   import React from "react";
   import MyOutlet from "./components/Router/MyOutlet";

   const App = () => {
     return (
       <div>
         <MyOutlet />
       </div>
     );
   };

   export default App;
   ```
4. Update the `Navigation` component to render just the links.

   ```
   import React from "react";
   import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

   const Navigation = () => {
     return (
       <div>
         <nav style={{ margin: 10 }}>
           <Link to="/" style={{ padding: 5 }}>
             Home
           </Link>
           <Link to="/about" style={{ padding: 5 }}>
             About
           </Link>
         </nav>
       </div>
     );
   };

   export default Navigation;
   ```

### Demo

[image: Edit failed-to-use-react-router-v6-navigation-from-login-to-home-with-navi]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Almost you got it. In the login `"/"` path I need just to render `Login` withouth menu. The page with menu would be displayed after redirecting in `Login` component

Comment: @Peter_Griffindor I see. Check the updated answer and linked sandbox demo.

Comment: Yeah, I see that important there is `NavLayout` and wrapping `Routes`, I am right? . Thank you sir for your advices and time.

Comment: @Peter_Griffindor Yes, that is what allows the "conditional" rendering of content to specific sub-sets of routes. In retrospect I think this might have been what you were trying/wanting to do with `MyOutlet`, and in this case you could replace the `MyOutlet` in `App` with the current `MyOutlet` implementation directly.

Answer (score 0):

router you need to **put your routes file in your app.js** so that your browser can render your routes first and this way you can have a **signle page application (SPA)** and always have a **route with path="/"** it's the first page that when someone visites your page see

i changed your app.js and MyOutlet hope this helps
[code that i edited in sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-routing-forked-dvsqxm?file=/src/components/Router/MyOutlet.jsx)

Comment: Better share code in answer than sandbox

Answer (score -1):

Hey Peter I had the same issues a while ago. While I can't point to you exactly whatsup without reading your code, Here is what saved me a lot.
Have a quick read here.
https://blog.logrocket.com/react-router-v6-guide/

Cheers!

Also, check if you wrapped your component routes like this;

```
<Router>
   <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
   </Routes>
 </Router>
```

Comment: Hi, my whole code is in codesandbox

Comment: Alright, that's a good way to go about it

Comment: The link you have provided is tutorial I have used for nav menu, but I have not found anything to help my problem

Comment: Ok, I now understand what you are trying to achieve, plus read through your exchange with Drew up there (He's a great guy btw) and I have gone through your code also and what I advise you to do is go back to that post and and follow the link to their Repo for the project since you used it in the first place. Their project has what you need just read that code on Github. (Personally reading through people's code has improved me a lot)  Cheers!